# Docker Desktop Update Hangs on macOS

Tags: docker

On my MacBook Pro (2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, 23 GB RAM) running macOS Sonoma 14.3.1, I am running Docker Desktop version 4.26.0 (130397). The latest version is 4.27.2 (137060).

When I try to install the update, it says "Installing update" for (roughly) ever. It seems never to progress.

I see Console log messages like:

```
default 10:13:51.045420-0500    install processes still running: Docker Desktop Docker Desktop Helper Docker Desktop Helper (GPU) Docker Desktop Helper (Renderer) com.docker.backend com.docker.build com.docker.dev-envs com.docker.extensions com.docker.virtualization
default 10:13:53.448829-0500    install processes still running: Docker Desktop Docker Desktop Helper Docker Desktop Helper (GPU) Docker Desktop Helper (Renderer) com.docker.backend com.docker.build com.docker.dev-envs com.docker.extensions com.docker.virtualization
default 10:13:54.655612-0500    install processes still running: Docker Desktop Docker Desktop Helper Docker Desktop Helper (GPU) Docker Desktop Helper (Renderer) com.docker.backend com.docker.build com.docker.dev-envs com.docker.extensions com.docker.virtualization
```

Anyone have advice on how they would proceed?

If this is the wrong place to ask such a question, I will be grateful if you suggest where I *should* ask.

Comment: Does the installer have any other logs indicating what is occurring? Are there any utilities which can show file or system activities you could use to determine what, if anything, the Docker installer is getting stuck on? Does it ever fail, or does it remain stuck until you end the task?